# Which of these two ways is better to report comparison of paired data?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, wilcoxon-signed-rank, reporting

Suppose I am comparing the computational time of two algorithms **A** and **B**. They are solving randomized problem **P**. Let's say I solved the problem for seeds $ 1, 2, \dots, n $ with both A and B and got the times:

$ a_1 , a_2, \dots , a_n $ for problem **A**

and

$ b_1 , b_2, \dots , b_n $ for problem **B**.

I can use the [Wilcoxon signed rank test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test) to see which algorithm performed better.

But suppose that I want to provide the reader with a sense of *magnitude*. That is I want to show just *how much* one is better than the other. For example:

> A is **12 times** faster than B on the average.

How should I compute this **average**? Should I use:

$$
avg = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{b_k}{a_k}
$$

or:

$$
avg =  \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n} b_k }{\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k }
$$
?

Comment: Suppose you were to address a collection of $n$ instances of $\mathcal{P}$ and could choose either algorithm to do it.  How would you compare the computational efforts then?

Comment: @whuber The second formula should be more relevant in this case